# Kept back package not updating

Tags: linux

I need help with a package that is being kept back.

When I run "`sudo apt-get upgrade`" I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libllvm12:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is there to fix? You (or something acting on behalf of you) have asked that that package (`libllwm12:i386`) is not upgraded, and it isn't. And it does not seem like there are other packages that can't be upgraded because of this.

Comment: so, do I need to fix the held package or not? should I just ignore it?

Comment: Haven't I already answered that? If you're going to going administrate that system, I suggest you spend some time learning how packages work.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity is the OP no trying to "learn how packages work" in this question?  And no you haven't answered the OP's follow up comment.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: I meant learning it deeper than what a single question here can do, and my first comment basically explains what it means that `libllvm12:i386` is on hold, basically answering what to do, so I did answer the follow-up question!

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity you don't seem to have explained anything beyond what is plainly in the warning.  What is the impact... why is this happening?  Answering those points may help the OP understand if they "need to fix or not".

Comment: also: Is it on Debian testing/unstable or on Ubuntu? etc.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: It's not a warning, it's just information. And beyond `libllvm12:i386` not being upgraded, how am I supposed to know the impact? I have already said that it seems like (currently) there's no other packages that can't be upgraded. Or why it was put on hold? The question contains absolutely no clue to that.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity that was my point. you didn't tell the OP if they *"need to fix the held package or not"*.  Seemed weird that you thought you had.

Answer (score 1):

When the package is held back it means it will be kept on the same version when you run an update.

You can hold back a package with `dpkg` command:

```
echo "libllvm12:i386 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

If you don't want your package to be held back, you can run:

```
echo "libllvm12:i386 install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can see what packages are held back with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

For more info see `man dpkg`